# Flickering of Window Border when UserControl used as a popup is focused

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, popup

I have a project that is using the [SuperContextMenu](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22780/Super-Context-Menu-Strip?fid=968284&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=1#xx0xx) project to build custom popup context menus for a WinForms project of mine.

The project works well and is built using the premise that a `UserControl` is hosted using the `ToolStripControlHost` wrapped up in a `ToolStripDropDown`. The project features two classes of importance here: `PoperContainer` that uses the `ToolStripDropDown` to host a `UserControl` based class `PopedCotainer`.

The `PopedCotainer` class is then used to build customised popups with buttons and other WinForm controls.

As mentioned, the project serves its purpose of being a customised way to build context menus/pop ups. Like the one seen below:
[Example Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23SGR.png)

The customized popup is then added to the form like below:

```
PoperContainer ContextMenuHost; 
public Form1() { 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    ContextMenuHost = new PoperContainer (userTest1); //Where userTest1 is a derived PopedCotainer 
}
```

My issue comes from when the Popup is focused upon (or any control within it). The form that hosts the popup will tend to flicker the form's border and title when the popup is focused. This doesn't always occur and can occur in different strengths of flickering, from inexistant, to very minor flickering, to absolutely flicking the border's color to white for a fraction of a second.

This occurs whenever the popup is opened and focused.

I have been able to narrow the problem down to this section in `PoperContainer`:

```
protected override void OnOpened(EventArgs e){
    m_popedContainer.Focus(); //This here causes the flicking 
    base.OnOpened(e); 
}
```

I have tried a few things to remove the flickering when trying to focus the popup. Firstly, not like it was intended to resolve this problem, but any `DoubleBuffer`ing has not resolved my issues with the occasional flickering with the form's border.

I cannot use `<control>.ShowDialog()` here as this is for a `UserControl` and using `<control>.Show()` whilst on the surface, does appear to remove the flickering when the popup is opened. It does not remove the form's border flickering when the popup or any of its child controls are clicked or `Focused`. `<parentform>.SuspendLayout()` and `<parentform>.ResumeLayout()` also have no affect here when trying to stop the flickering.

I have also tried: `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` with no avail. I have also tried to call the form's `<parent form>.Focus()` method directly after focusing to the popup or any of its controls.

I don't want a dialog box or form, I am looking for the same functionality that a traditional `ContextMenuStrip` provides, but only with the ability to customize it with a layout with buttons are other controls.

Is anyone able to help resolve this annoying problem.
Kind Regards.